# When to reset temp variable in this Python procedure?

Tags: python, logic

I'm trying to find the column wise combinations for given m x n 2d matrix. For example if the matrix is 3 x 3, it might be,

```
1  2  3

4  5  6

7  8  9
```

And I want the combinations, 3 at time, like -

```
1, 4, 7
1, 4, 8
1, 4, 9
1, 5, 7
.
.
1, 6, 7
```

I've tried the following recursive procedure in Python 3:

```js
def getKeys(keychars):
    temp = []
    create(keychars, 0, 0, temp)

def create(kc, i, j, temp):
    if i == 3:
        print(temp)
        del temp[-1]
        return
    temp.append(kc[i][j])
    for j in range(3):
        create(kc, i+1, j, temp)


def main():
    keychars = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
    getKeys(keychars)

main()
```

(If running the snippet gives you an error, please try in an IDE.)

But the problem is that, I'm not sure how or when to clear the temp variable. The outputs are like - 1,4,7  1,4,7,8   1,4,7,8,9   1,4,7,8,9,5
That is the temp variable retains the previous results. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What language is the proc you posted?

Comment: btw your snippet didn't run when I tried, just throws an error: `{
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 12,
  "colno": 13
}`

Comment: try running on an ide, https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/  it's on python 3